# Eclipse- Maven -Spring

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven

I installed eclipse Luna.At that time Maven option was displayed in window-- preferences.Later i install spring ide.After installation maven got disappeared.pls help me to come out of this

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is well known for working oddly despite the correct settings and configuration. (As most of free IDEs').

Try to click to your project, then **Configure** and select **Convert to Maven project**.

Also clicking to your project and selecting the **Clean** may help since it removes all the files that are generated automatically.